# Facebook extended permissions error in Java Script

Tags: facebook, permissions, fb.ui

My app wants to request extended permissions if a user wants to use certain features. I am not able to get the FB.UI dialog box to pop up. My code is below (and it really does not seem that complicated):

```
function getPublishPermission(appId){
 FB.init({ app_id:appId, cookie:true, status:true, oauth:true });
 var obj = {
     method: 'permissions.request',
     perms: 'publish_stream',
     display: 'iframe'
 };
 FB.ui(obj, earnCallback);
}
```

I receive an error that says: "An error occurred. Please try again later."
I have used scope instead of perms with the same result. The appId is passed correctly (same error when I hardcode the appId). The sandbox mode is switched off. Just what am I missing?

Comment: And other things I have tried in the meantime: used authResponse: true, tried using display: 'popup' and added a channel callback. Nothing works. Strangely, I don't evens see the error anymore - instead the authorization dialog just spins.
Any help is deeply deeply appreciated.

Comment: Using Firebug, I found that the appId is not being set:
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?perms=publish_stream&display=iframe&e2e=%7B%7D&app_id=&locale=en_US
Why would that be? I have tried hardcoding the app id into FB.Init() and even then the app id does not make it to the extended permissions URL

Comment: 3 days of insanity later, it turns it that is is appId and not app_id:
    FB.init({ appId:appId, cookie:true, status:true, oauth:true });

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is not app_id, but appId:
    FB.init({ appId:appId, cookie:true, status:true, oauth:true });